# pywinauto : Cannot find Active Windows, but the Focus is already on the Window

Tags: python, pyautogui, pywinauto

[My GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maiYa.png)

First i used click on the "RPA Job Closure" to popup a windows: Job Closure.

I used pyautogui to detect active windows to retrieve the title to make sure the focus is on the Job Closure and not the backend windows: Syspro. On the console, it correct prompted: Job Closure.

Then i used pyautowin to grab the parameters but it is saying not found.

My objectives is to detect the Job Textbox, enter a series of numbers and click POST Button.

On my Console:

```
Job Closure
Found Job Closure
Cannot find Job Closure {'title': 'Job Closure', 'backend': 'uia', 'visible_only': False}
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This is my Code:

```
try:
       window_title = pyautogui.getActiveWindowTitle()
       print(window_title)
       print("Found Job Closure")
       app3 = Application(backend='uia').connect(title='Job Closure')
       app3.JobClosure.print_control_identifiers()
     except Exception as e:
       # Handle the case where the pop-up didn't appear
       print("Cannot find Job Closure", e)
```